# Method return and reset a property at the same time?

Tags: php

Lets start with this example class:

```
class Widget {
    private static $items = [];
    public static function resetitems() { self::$items = []; }
    public static function getitems()   { return self::$items; }
    public static function doobie() {
        // does something and adds a ton of junk to self::$items
    }
}
```

Now a way to get and reset the property can be done as such:

```
    Widget::doobie();
    $items = Widget::getitems();
    Widget::resetitems();
```

However, instead of always having to call `resetitems` after `getitems` (when the intent is *always* to get *and* reset), I'm trying to find a more elegant way to just have `getitems` do this automatically during the return.

I ***could*** do this:

```
    public static function getitems() {
        $wasteofspace = self::$items;
        self::resetitems();
        return $wasteofspace;
    }
```

But shouldn't there be a way to return the direct property itself AND call reset at the same time? Something like this (but this will not work obviously haha):

```
    public static function getitems() {
        return self::$items & self::resetitems();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_splice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
    public static function get_and_reset_items() {
        return array_splice(self::$items, 0);
    }
```

Comment: A very ingenious notion. I was skeptical at first, but that actually works. Ran some tests and nothing seemed to stuff the process.

Comment: Just to note: This only works with properties that are an `array`. Won't work with other types of property. However for my needs, this works as I needed it. Thanks.

Comment: @IncredibleHat You're right, it only works for arrays. Personnally, I would just use your first attempt: even if it is more verbose, it is also more clear (to my eyes), and gives more flexibility as you just wrote.

Comment: Yes... visually (reading it later), I'm sure I'm going to go "wth is this actually doing again?" :-) Or if someone inherits the code, they will boggle what was I thinking.

Comment: After doing some benchmarking on using `array_splice` vs my `getitems` method in the Q... the `array_splice` return is 500% slower, and somehow leaves extra memory in use after the fact (like after looping 10k times, more ram was still allocated, than when not using array_splice). I reran the benches, fiddled, and same results. So although this answer is pretty slick, I'm going back to the multi-line `getitems` method I had in the Q.